# Entity Framework - loading entities by multiple navigation properties in one request

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Good afternoon, everyone! I've got a new  question: assume that I have the following entity in my database:

```
public class Entity1
{
public virtual Entity2 Navigation1 {get;set;}
public virtual Entity3 Navigation2 {get; set;}
......
}
```

And I need is to execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Entity1 ent1
join Entity2 as ent2 on ent2.Id = ent1.Entity2Id
join Entity3 as ent3 on ent3.Id = ent1.Entity3Id
```

If I code this way:

```
context.Entry(ent1).Reference(rep=>rep.Navigation1).Load();
context.Entry(ent1).Reference(rep=>rep.Navigation2).Load();
```

Entity Framework will execute 2 queries. How am I supposed to rewrite the code so that the framework performs only one call to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to utilize the navigation properties.

For example:

```
IQueryable<Entity1> query = DBContext.Set<Entity1>()
    .Include(x => x.Navigation1)
    .Include(x => x.Navigation2);

IList<Entity1> mylist = query.ToList();
```

mylist would then contain your entity with properties set matching your associated entities.